# how to enable filestream in SQL Server 2008 without SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm trying to enable Filestream in SQL Server 2008 and I Do not have  SQL Server Management Studio component installed on my computer, all info I've found already needs the Management studio, how could I enable it without it? thanks

Comment: You'll need the configuration tool as well, which is part of the same set of client tools. If you're going to be using SQL Server, why don't you just install Management Studio and the other client tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using sqlcmd utility enter the following commands:

```
USE master
Go
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options'
GO
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

There are 3 levels of FILESTREAM access which are supported in SQL Server 2008 and they are mentioned below for your reference.

- When the value specified is 0 then, FILESTREAM support for the instance is Disabled
- When the value specified is 1 then, FILESTREAM for Transact-SQL Access is Enabled
- When the value specified is 2 then, FILESTREAM for Transact-SQL and Windows streaming access is Enabled

look at this page (http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1838) for more info.

Comment: -1 because the documentation says that this has no effect unless you configure the OS as well, using the SQL Server Configuration Tool

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use sp_configure to set the FILESTREAM access level, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645956.aspx) notes that it has no effect unless Windows is also configured using the SQL Server Configuration tool.

Assuming that the server is under your or your company's internal control, you can just RDP to it and use the tools installed on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the OS portion using WMI. Here's some details on this along with a downloadable script:

http://sqlsrvengine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FileStreamEnable

After doing this you'll still need to enable through osql or similar like Alex_L's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To enable FILESTREAM feature on SQL Server 2008, you can use  SQL Server Configuration Manager :

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager (Start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager)
2. Navigate to the SQL Server Services node and select the SQL Server instance you want to modify SQL Server
3. Click the FILESTREAM tab and select the checkboxes to enable FILESTREAM and enter a share name for the files

[image]

Comment: I have seen this option too but it needs some configuration with Management Studio.